# Chrome Google Dictionary extension on local html page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have the chrome google dictionary extension installed. I have a simple html page in my desktop called test.html and I kept some text in it. But when I open the page in google chrome and double click on any word it does not open any pop up box. But the extension works for any other websites.

Anything am I missing?

Here is the sample test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1" />

</head>

<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>
Till och med självmorden betedde sig illa i Wyoming Valley.
Pojken i motellrummet hade bara ett par boxershorts på sig och låg i fosterställning ovanpå det beiga, indianmönstrade sängöverkastet. Han var högst arton år gammal; halvlångt, rågblont hår, breda axlar, smal om höfterna. Runt vänster biceps var en slips stramt åtdragen, och strax intill de slutna ögonen vilade en tömd uppdragningskanyl som tycktes vara det sista han skådat i jordelivet.
Det var inte första gången George Decker, Bear Creeks polischef, såg ett lik. Han hade tjänstgjort i marinkåren under invasionen av Grenada. Och under de gångna femton åren i Pennsylvanias fattigaste region hade han tappat räkningen: jaktolyckor, bilolyckor med och utan vilt, urspårade knivslagsmål – ett och annat kallblodigt mord, till och med. Men den här gången var det annorlunda. Pojken såg mest ut att ligga och sova, även om han hade spytt ner sig. Det var något med hans ungdom, med att han inte hade råkat ut för en deformerande olycka, som gjorde det hela så mycket mer tragiskt än de fasor Decker sett efter bilkrascher och granatattacker. Det var själva frivilligheten.
För det måste vara självmord, inte en vanlig överdos. Papper och penna på ena nattduksbordet, kläder prydligt hopvikta över en stolsrygg.
Rummet var det billigaste man kunde hitta på flera mils omkrets. Väggarna hade ingen klassificerbar färg. Teven, en burkig tjugotummare som genomlevt decennier i fångenskap, stod fastkedjad ovanpå ett kylskåp med träpanel. Det lilakaklade trånga badrummet var fuktigt som en ångbastu och fläkten överröstade nästan dånet från motorvägen utanför. Alla lampor var tända, ändå var det som om mörkret där inne var för kompakt för att riktigt låta sig skingras. Mellan heltäckningsmattan och det rötskadade rågolvet hade man stoppat tidningspapper som gjorde att det frasade när man gick.
Deckers assistent, en kvinna som luktade hårfärgningsmedel var tredje vecka och alltid harklade sig när det var tyst för länge, klev åt sidan när han gick förbi och förde undan de skotskrutiga gardinerna. Genom fönstren syntes morgondimman ånga in från bergen och sakta dra ner över dalgången.
Han strök handen över skäggstubben.
”Vem är det?”
”Christopher Warsinsky”, sa assistenten och läste vidare på körkortet. ”237 Lakeron Drive. Skulle ha fyllt sjutton om två månader.”
”Bilnycklar?”
”Nej.”
”Hur kom han hit då?” Decker såg sig omkring i rummet.
”Det ligger en busshållplats tvåhundra meter bort. Eller så fick han skjuts.”
På ena nattduksbordet stod en tom, öppen medicinflaska. Decker böjde sig fram och luktade utan att plocka upp den. Ingen doft alls. Heroin, naturligtvis.
”Kolla här”, sa assistenten vid det andra bordet och lyfte papperet med en pincett.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension doesn't work with local files.  It has been suggested for future versions. A workaround suggested is importing things into google docs.  I know its not an ideal solution.  Good luck.

There are offline dictionary chrome extensions that will do this for you.  I am not sure how they compare.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because you are accessing to local file, so you use the "protocol" `file://path/to/test.html`. But I think that in your manifest.json, you have injected your content scripts by `"http://*/*"` pattern.

When you load local file, you don't use HTTP protocol. So you have to modify your manifest or install a local web server on your machine (like WAMP if using windows or LAMP if using linux or MAMP if using macos).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the extensions page (chrome://extensions/), find Google Dictionary and click on "Details". You'll find an option that says "Allow access to file URLs".